# html - background image в svg элемент

Tags: html, css, svg

Делаю интерактивную карту, сама карта нарисована сделана в svg и разбита по районам.

[image: Карта]
Нужно в эти районы еще вставить картинки, чтоб было так:

[image: Карта с фото]
Но проблема в том, что отображается нормально она только в Firefox, в Chrome и Opera эта же картинка очень размытая, а в том же Firefox при наведении на эту область все начинает сильно тормозить...

Вот часть кода с начала карты и этого района с фото:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="svg2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1771.6535
1771.6535" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1771.6535 1771.6535;" xml:space="preserve">
  
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img1" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <image xlink:href="./Regions/Arbuzinka.png" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="30%" height="30%" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  
  
  <a class="Arbuzinka" href="http://arbuzinkabib.tk">
    <g
      inkscape:groupmode="layer"
      id="layer18"
      inkscape:label="Арбузинка"
      style="display:inline"
      transform="translate(0,719.29131)">
      <path
        class="region"
        d="m 629.95741,-565.91816 -8.12988,-0.12207 -0.0732,5.44434 -6.5918,-0.19532
        -0.34179,8.44727 -4.68754,-0.0244 -0.1709,6.03027 -2.417,5.46875 1.001,10.4248
        1.3183,5.78614 2.6368,19.09179 -6.2989,3.24707 0.708,11.18164 -67.1374,30.41936
        -0.5006,20.95771 5.9731,2.90024 0.086,0.0345 -2.7967,12.74035 -11.1862,15.28424
        -3.1616,2.51465 -2.1179,3.76587 3.1298,3.97637 -2.2326,19.18647 8.5855,17.2133
        6.2925,6.95713 4.7647,3.50446 6.2972,0.34025 5.5664,9.79005 5.1514,13.35449
        3.7598,7.56836 1.1718,3.51562 3.125,3.90625 2.5391,4.29688 -0.1953,1.95312 -1.3672,3.32032 -1.1719,3.90625 -1.3672,2.73437 -2.539,2.92969 -1.7578,4.10156
        -0.586,1.95313 1.3672,1.75781 3.125,1.75781 2.5391,1.5625 2.9297,0.78125
        3.9062,0.58594 2.3438,0 3.7109,0.58594 2.3438,1.17187 3.3203,1.36719 3.5156,2.14844
        2.3437,1.75781 1.7579,0.68359 1.6601,1.85547 1.2695,0.68359 -0.3906,2.63672
        -0.5859,3.51563 -0.6836,1.36719 -0.293,2.14843 0.7813,1.17188 0.9765,1.75781
        2.5606,6.38337 0.6215,1.38107 0.6215,1.86444 0.2762,1.9335 c 0,0 0.2762,0.69053
        0.1381,0.96675 -0.1381,0.27621 -0.5524,1.93349 -0.5524,1.93349 l 0.069,1.31202
        -0.8977,1.86444 c 0,0 -0.1381,1.24296 -0.2071,1.58823 -0.069,0.34526 0.069,1.51917
        0.069,1.79538 0,0.27622 0.069,0.82864 0.069,1.24297 0,0.41432 -0.2072,1.86444
        -0.2072,1.86444 l -0.1192,2.92068 0.293,1.36719 -0.4883,1.75781 0,0.87891 0,1.46484
        0.293,1.07422 0.6836,0.78125 1.3672,1.36719 c 0,0 0.8789,1.17187 1.0742,1.5625
        0.1953,0.39062 0.7812,0.78125 0.8789,1.46484 0.098,0.6836 0.098,1.17188
        0.098,1.17188 0,0 0.098,0.19531 0.3906,0.78125 0.293,0.58593 0.6836,1.36718
        0.6836,1.36718 l 0.098,0.48829 8.00789,-1.07422 27.83203,-7.22657 -0.87891,-8.00781
        -2.24609,-8.10547 3.80859,-0.58593 -0.0977,-4.88282 5.95703,-2.24609 0.97656,-
        4.98047 2.24609,-2.05078 2.83204,3.61328 12.98828,29.88281 6.83593,-1.46484
        3.61329,-2.05078 20.50781,-3.71094 12.5,-3.71094 -1.75781,-16.11328 0.92773,-3.36914
        20.70313,-1.95312 1.31835,7.61718 1.98143,5.99878 6.90529,-0.38354 11.42578,-2.88086
        -3.72627,-19.28154 0.62148,-2.27876 6.90534,-1.0358 -3.93605,-25.3426 -1.45012,-
        3.79793 -1.24296,-2.20971 2.48592,-1.45012 8.15516,-1.29299 4.58985,-0.73243
        3.95508,-1.61132 0.73242,-1.07422 -0.87891,-5.07813 -2.24609,-7.91015 -16.37911,-
        67.99604 -1.79539,-7.18155 -5.52427,-24.72112 -1.51917,-2.34781 -0.7098,-4.19881
        -6.34765,0.14649 -1.07422,-1.12305 -1.31836,-11.18164 -7.66602,-2.7832 -3.18565,-
        15.6627 0.69053,-2.62403 5.38617,-0.13811 -5.52428,-45.16092 2.62403,0.27621
        0.82864,-0.82864 -1.60069,-14.76806 -4.29687,0.29297 0.39062,-18.65235 -3.22265,0
        -4.10157,9.66797 -7.74675,9.71784 -14.95832,1.8056 -8.1543,4.66308 -1.46484,-
        29.19921 -3.95508,-1.61133 -3.51563,0.75684 -32.32422,14.55077 -5.88379,1.00098
        -0.78125,-0.0732 -0.63476,-0.43946 -0.53711,-0.63476 -1.87988,-4.3457 1.66015,-
        2.70996 2.27051,0.39062 -4.69971,-19.86694 -2.47802,-3.32642 z"
        id="path3343"
        fill="url(#img1)"
        inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    </g>
  </a>
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров Нет, она всегда отображается, при наведении просто выделяется этот район слева в списке.

Answer (score 3):

**Только как для примера!**

Я использую js для того чтобы вычислить ширину, высоту каждой ячейки `path` и ее положение, данные передаю `image`.

```js
// 1 Картинка по размерам ячейки
$('path').each( function(){
  var $this = $(this),
    $width = $this[0].getBBox().width,
    $height = $this[0].getBBox().height,
    $top = $this.offset().top,
    $left = $this.offset().left;

  var imgSrc = $this.data('img'),
    img = $('#'+imgSrc).find('image');

  img.width($width);
  img.height($height);
  img.attr({'x': $left, 'y': $top});

});
```

```css
html,
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

path {
cursor:pointer;
}

path:not(:hover) {
fill: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500"  preserveAspectRatio="none">  


  <defs>
      <pattern id="img-1" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="100%" width="100%">
          <image x="0" y="0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496857239036-1fb137683000?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" width="68" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" />
      </pattern>

      <pattern id="img-2" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="100%" width="100%">
          <image x="0" y="0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523049673857-eb18f1d7b578?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" width="68" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" />
      </pattern>

      <pattern id="img-3" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="100%" width="100%">
          <image x="0" y="0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501086975536-1220c4cf61f0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" width="68" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" />
      </pattern>



  </defs>

  <g>
    <path fill="url(#img-1)" data-img="img-1" stroke="#646464" d="M55.361,284.361c0-1.473,1.263-3.998,2.21-6.523c0.947-2.525,2.946-3.894,3.893-5.788
      c0.947-1.894,1.789-1.789,1.789-3.156c0-1.368-3.367-5.156-4.63-6.419s0.315-3.052,0.315-3.052s0.526-3.683,0.526-6.419
      c0-2.736,0-3.473,0-4.946s1.473-1.999,2.104-3.999c0.631-1.999,0-2.315,0-3.472c0-1.158,2.209-4.209,2.209-5.156
      c0-0.947-1.841-4.578-1.578-5.998s3.683-2.525,4.84-3.683c1.158-1.157,2.525-5.682,1.789-6.418
      c-0.737-0.737-1.579-1.579-1.052-5.051c0.313-2.065,2.967-4.311,5.07-5.797c-0.176-0.22-0.422-0.525-0.832-1.053
      c-1.331-1.716,0.456-3.921-0.455-6.337c-0.91-2.417-4.377-5.742-5.392-6.023c-1.015-0.28-1.085-0.245-3.256-1.084
      c-2.171-0.841-2.836-1.856-4.553-2.837c-1.716-0.98-3.221-1.471-4.622-2.381c-1.401-0.911-1.558-0.578-2.381,0.245
      c-0.823,0.824-2.73,4.272-4.657,4.553c-1.926,0.28-2.101-0.386-3.256-1.016c-1.155-0.63-3.956-2.066-4.237-1.786
      c-0.28,0.28-4.097-1.541-6.092-1.961c-1.995-0.42-2.241-2.24-4.798-1.506c-2.556,0.736-1.96,4.202-1.96,4.938
      s-0.438,0.998-1.261,1.821c-0.822,0.823-1.454,4.5-1.787,4.833c-0.332,0.333-0.192,1.907-0.525,2.591
      c-0.332,0.682-0.77,0.42-1.365,2.871c-0.595,2.452,2.136,2.731,2.486,4.867c0.35,2.136-0.245,1.401-0.875,1.716
      c-0.631,0.315-0.771,0.77-1.226,1.225c-0.455,0.455,0.455,1.085-0.175,1.716c-0.63,0.63-1.891,0.595-3.641,0.98
      c-1.751,0.386-2.451,4.237-2.451,7.284c0,3.046-0.946,1.611-1.261,1.926c-0.315,0.314-4.692,0.771-6.058,0.315
      c-1.365-0.456-1.488-0.473-2.346,0.385c-0.858,0.857-0.315,3.116,0.139,4.062c0.456,0.946,0.876,0,3.887,1.891
      c3.012,1.891,3.958,4.447,5.007,5.813c1.05,1.366,2.171,0,2.346,1.785c0.175,1.787,0.788,3.73,1.19,4.133
      c0.403,0.402,0.7,0.84,0.911,2.17c0.209,1.331-1.121,1.856,0.175,4.237c1.296,2.38,5.497,4.483,6.373,4.903s0,2.276,2.662,4.026
      c2.662,1.751,6.093,2.767,7.704,3.816c1.611,1.05,1.611,0.07,3.116,0.666c1.506,0.595-0.14,3.886-0.14,5.708
      c0,1.82,4.115,4.219,5.287,4.972c1.173,0.751,1.085,1.504,1.435,2.729c0.496,1.735,0.825,5.008,0.707,8.505
      C51.074,284.678,55.361,285.426,55.361,284.361z"/>

    <path fill="url(#img-2)" data-img="img-2" stroke="#646464" d="M77.774,405.863c2.386,0.701,2.386-2.034,2.386-3.788c0-1.755,0.491-2.876,1.473-4.841
      s3.893-4.104,4.63-4.84c0.737-0.737,4.98-1.333,5.472-2.666c0.491-1.332,4.419-1.333,6.489-2.14s-1.192-1.191-1.789-1.789
      c-0.596-0.597-0.14-4.209-1.403-6.173s-1.192-3.508-1.192-4.56c0-1.053,1.753-3.508,1.753-4.489c0-0.982-0.912-3.859,2.035-4.981
      c0.986-0.376,1.392-1.518,1.504-2.865c-0.01-0.006-0.021-0.001-0.031-0.011c-0.526-0.526-4.209-3.017-6.173-3.368
      c-1.964-0.351-4.279-1.122-6.945-2.665s-3.507-2.735-5.682-2.735s-3.578-1.896-4.701-3.018s-9.68-7.154-11.925-9.399
      s-4.384-2.28-5.191-1.474c-0.807,0.808-2.876,2.104-3.929,2.455c-1.052,0.351-2.385-0.981-4.84-4.77
      c-1.098-1.694-3.795-3.064-6.441-4.063c-0.838,1.651-1.504,3.306-1.44,4.728c0,0.017,0.001,0.031,0.001,0.047
      c0,0.98,1.418,0.893,1.751,0.56c0.333-0.334,2.38-0.314,2.941,0.244c2.141,2.149,0.961,14.104-1.173,16.268
      c-0.549,0.556-0.835,1.193-0.438,1.592c0.403,0.402,2.941,0.699,3.222,1.785s-0.192,2.223,0.385,2.8
      c0.578,0.578,0.91,6.27,0.91,6.935c0,0.664-0.525,1.716-1.366,2.555c-0.84,0.843-0.367,2.925-0.98,3.537
      c-0.613,0.614-1.996,1.155-2.731,2.593c-0.735,1.436,1.891,3.5,3.082,6.268c1.19,2.766,3.187,1.61,3.642,3.501
      c0.456,1.891,3.711,0.736,5.637,1.12c1.926,0.386,3.362,1.928,3.047,3.292c-0.315,1.366-1.541-0.071-2.521,2.416
      c-0.981,2.486,0.071,1.401,0.49,2.765c0.421,1.367,1.227,3.118,0.421,4.659c-0.806,1.54-0.911,2.414-0.911,3.921
      c0,1.506,1.505,1.505,4.867,1.821c2.344,0.219,3.902-0.511,4.763,0.117c1.746-1.201,3.76-2.399,5.432-2.886
      C76.161,403.198,75.389,405.162,77.774,405.863z"/>

    <path fill="url(#img-3)" data-img="img-3" stroke="#646464" d="M167.006,368.053c-0.596-1.438-3.157-2.315-3.999-3.157s-0.281-4.771,0.421-6.945
      c0.702-2.174,1.263-3.156,0.982-4.98s-5.366-3.473-6.734-4.841s-3.297-3.297-5.331-6.454c-2.035-3.157-4.35-2.034-9.12-2.665
      c-4.77-0.632-4.349,0.28-6.173,0.28s0,2.806,0.351,3.929s-0.421,2.736-1.824,1.895s-2.736-2.176-4.279-4.631
      c-1.543-2.454-2.456-1.754-3.929-3.228c-1.473-1.473-6.594,0.913-7.646,1.403c-1.052,0.491-3.963,2.421-4.84,1.544
      c-0.877-0.878-1.543-3.228-3.367-4.35s-1.298,5.857-1.894,6.454c-0.597,0.596-3.087,7.085-2.525,8.278
      c0.562,1.192-0.141,2.244-0.141,3.156c0,0.913-2.736,2.034-3.718,2.315c-0.982,0.281-2.596,1.332-2.596,1.894
      c0,0.551-0.979,5.111-1.513,4.781c-0.112,1.348-0.518,2.489-1.504,2.865c-2.946,1.122-2.035,3.999-2.035,4.981
      c0,0.981-1.753,3.437-1.753,4.489c0,1.052-0.07,2.596,1.192,4.56s0.807,5.576,1.403,6.173c0.597,0.598,3.858,0.982,1.789,1.789
      s-5.998,0.808-6.489,2.14c-0.491,1.333-4.735,1.929-5.472,2.666c-0.737,0.736-3.647,2.875-4.63,4.84s-1.473,3.086-1.473,4.841
      c0,1.754,0,4.489-2.386,3.788c-2.385-0.701-1.613-2.665-5.472-1.543c-1.672,0.486-3.686,1.685-5.432,2.886
      c0.374,0.272,0.618,0.797,0.734,1.772c0.384,3.222-0.071,9.665-0.071,10.121c0,0.454,0,0.805-0.385,1.188
      c-0.385,0.386-0.805,0.981-0.805,1.892c0,0.912,2.837,0.771,4.097,0.35c1.261-0.419,4.832-1.819,6.934-1.364
      c2.101,0.454,7.896,3.624,8.544,4.272c0.647,0.648,3.816,1.154,4.062,3.815c0.245,2.66-2.171,3.012-2.346,3.816
      c-0.175,0.806-1.172,1.77-1.751,2.348c-0.578,0.577-1.401,0.874-1.995,1.05c-0.595,0.176-0.263,1.664-0.035,1.891
      c0.228,0.227,2.801-0.385,3.991-1.017c1.19-0.63,4.238-0.943,7.844-0.734c3.606,0.209,4.482,3.571,6.793,4.201
      c2.311,0.631,3.571-0.805,3.921-1.89c0.351-1.087,2.941,0.104,3.327-1.156c0.385-1.26,3.274-6.041,3.852-6.618
      s4.027-0.734,6.863-1.576c2.836-0.84,8.999-4.481,9.419-6.197c0.419-1.716,4.587-5.495,5.708-5.742
      c1.12-0.245,3.432-0.489,3.677-1.751c0.245-1.26-1.016-2.205-2.066-1.996c-1.05,0.211-1.156,0.422-2.662-0.279
      c-1.506-0.7,0.596-2.941,0.875-4.308c0.281-1.366-1.715-0.664-1.925-5.006c-0.211-4.342,1.855-7.039,4.762-6.863
      c2.907,0.174,4.833-0.806,5.113-2.558c0.28-1.75,0.42-5.601-0.036-6.547c-0.456-0.945-1.961,1.226-2.835,1.226
      c-0.876,0-1.786-4.762-0.841-6.688c0.946-1.928,0.806-1.646-0.14-4.098c-0.945-2.45,5.428-2.45,6.688-2.45
      c1.26,0,0.979,0.735,1.75,1.506c0.771,0.769,3.117,0.209,3.782,0.559c0.665,0.352,2.328,2.436,3.012,3.117
      c0.264,0.264,0.462,0.376,0.633,0.39c0.739-1.667,2.02-3.534,2.25-4.5c0.351-1.473,1.333-1.753,5.401-3.016
      S167.603,369.49,167.006,368.053z"/>


  </g>

</svg>
```

Получается не совсем красиво и не по центру.

Взяла как для примера еще вариант с увеличенным в 1.5 раза `image` и центрированием в ячейке:

```js
//2 Картинка в 1.5 раза больше ячейки и центрируется
$('path').each(function() {

  var $this = $(this),
    $width = $this[0].getBBox().width,
    $height = $this[0].getBBox().height,
    $top = $this.offset().top,
    $left = $this.offset().left;

  var imgSrc = $this.data('img'),
    img = $('#' + imgSrc).find('image');

  img.width(1.5 * $width);
  img.height(1.5 * $height);

  img.attr({
    'x': $left - $width / 2,
    'y': $top - $height / 2
  });

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

path {
  cursor: pointer;
}

path:not(:hover) {
  fill: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500"  preserveAspectRatio="none">  

  <defs>
      <pattern id="img-1" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="100%" width="100%">
          <image x="0" y="0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496857239036-1fb137683000?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" width="68" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" />
      </pattern>

      <pattern id="img-2" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="100%" width="100%">
          <image x="0" y="0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523049673857-eb18f1d7b578?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" width="68" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" />
      </pattern>

      <pattern id="img-3" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="100%" width="100%">
          <image x="0" y="0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501086975536-1220c4cf61f0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" width="68" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" />
      </pattern>

  </defs>

  <g>
    <path fill="url(#img-1)" data-img="img-1" stroke="#646464" d="M55.361,284.361c0-1.473,1.263-3.998,2.21-6.523c0.947-2.525,2.946-3.894,3.893-5.788
      c0.947-1.894,1.789-1.789,1.789-3.156c0-1.368-3.367-5.156-4.63-6.419s0.315-3.052,0.315-3.052s0.526-3.683,0.526-6.419
      c0-2.736,0-3.473,0-4.946s1.473-1.999,2.104-3.999c0.631-1.999,0-2.315,0-3.472c0-1.158,2.209-4.209,2.209-5.156
      c0-0.947-1.841-4.578-1.578-5.998s3.683-2.525,4.84-3.683c1.158-1.157,2.525-5.682,1.789-6.418
      c-0.737-0.737-1.579-1.579-1.052-5.051c0.313-2.065,2.967-4.311,5.07-5.797c-0.176-0.22-0.422-0.525-0.832-1.053
      c-1.331-1.716,0.456-3.921-0.455-6.337c-0.91-2.417-4.377-5.742-5.392-6.023c-1.015-0.28-1.085-0.245-3.256-1.084
      c-2.171-0.841-2.836-1.856-4.553-2.837c-1.716-0.98-3.221-1.471-4.622-2.381c-1.401-0.911-1.558-0.578-2.381,0.245
      c-0.823,0.824-2.73,4.272-4.657,4.553c-1.926,0.28-2.101-0.386-3.256-1.016c-1.155-0.63-3.956-2.066-4.237-1.786
      c-0.28,0.28-4.097-1.541-6.092-1.961c-1.995-0.42-2.241-2.24-4.798-1.506c-2.556,0.736-1.96,4.202-1.96,4.938
      s-0.438,0.998-1.261,1.821c-0.822,0.823-1.454,4.5-1.787,4.833c-0.332,0.333-0.192,1.907-0.525,2.591
      c-0.332,0.682-0.77,0.42-1.365,2.871c-0.595,2.452,2.136,2.731,2.486,4.867c0.35,2.136-0.245,1.401-0.875,1.716
      c-0.631,0.315-0.771,0.77-1.226,1.225c-0.455,0.455,0.455,1.085-0.175,1.716c-0.63,0.63-1.891,0.595-3.641,0.98
      c-1.751,0.386-2.451,4.237-2.451,7.284c0,3.046-0.946,1.611-1.261,1.926c-0.315,0.314-4.692,0.771-6.058,0.315
      c-1.365-0.456-1.488-0.473-2.346,0.385c-0.858,0.857-0.315,3.116,0.139,4.062c0.456,0.946,0.876,0,3.887,1.891
      c3.012,1.891,3.958,4.447,5.007,5.813c1.05,1.366,2.171,0,2.346,1.785c0.175,1.787,0.788,3.73,1.19,4.133
      c0.403,0.402,0.7,0.84,0.911,2.17c0.209,1.331-1.121,1.856,0.175,4.237c1.296,2.38,5.497,4.483,6.373,4.903s0,2.276,2.662,4.026
      c2.662,1.751,6.093,2.767,7.704,3.816c1.611,1.05,1.611,0.07,3.116,0.666c1.506,0.595-0.14,3.886-0.14,5.708
      c0,1.82,4.115,4.219,5.287,4.972c1.173,0.751,1.085,1.504,1.435,2.729c0.496,1.735,0.825,5.008,0.707,8.505
      C51.074,284.678,55.361,285.426,55.361,284.361z"/>

    <path fill="url(#img-2)" data-img="img-2" stroke="#646464" d="M77.774,405.863c2.386,0.701,2.386-2.034,2.386-3.788c0-1.755,0.491-2.876,1.473-4.841
      s3.893-4.104,4.63-4.84c0.737-0.737,4.98-1.333,5.472-2.666c0.491-1.332,4.419-1.333,6.489-2.14s-1.192-1.191-1.789-1.789
      c-0.596-0.597-0.14-4.209-1.403-6.173s-1.192-3.508-1.192-4.56c0-1.053,1.753-3.508,1.753-4.489c0-0.982-0.912-3.859,2.035-4.981
      c0.986-0.376,1.392-1.518,1.504-2.865c-0.01-0.006-0.021-0.001-0.031-0.011c-0.526-0.526-4.209-3.017-6.173-3.368
      c-1.964-0.351-4.279-1.122-6.945-2.665s-3.507-2.735-5.682-2.735s-3.578-1.896-4.701-3.018s-9.68-7.154-11.925-9.399
      s-4.384-2.28-5.191-1.474c-0.807,0.808-2.876,2.104-3.929,2.455c-1.052,0.351-2.385-0.981-4.84-4.77
      c-1.098-1.694-3.795-3.064-6.441-4.063c-0.838,1.651-1.504,3.306-1.44,4.728c0,0.017,0.001,0.031,0.001,0.047
      c0,0.98,1.418,0.893,1.751,0.56c0.333-0.334,2.38-0.314,2.941,0.244c2.141,2.149,0.961,14.104-1.173,16.268
      c-0.549,0.556-0.835,1.193-0.438,1.592c0.403,0.402,2.941,0.699,3.222,1.785s-0.192,2.223,0.385,2.8
      c0.578,0.578,0.91,6.27,0.91,6.935c0,0.664-0.525,1.716-1.366,2.555c-0.84,0.843-0.367,2.925-0.98,3.537
      c-0.613,0.614-1.996,1.155-2.731,2.593c-0.735,1.436,1.891,3.5,3.082,6.268c1.19,2.766,3.187,1.61,3.642,3.501
      c0.456,1.891,3.711,0.736,5.637,1.12c1.926,0.386,3.362,1.928,3.047,3.292c-0.315,1.366-1.541-0.071-2.521,2.416
      c-0.981,2.486,0.071,1.401,0.49,2.765c0.421,1.367,1.227,3.118,0.421,4.659c-0.806,1.54-0.911,2.414-0.911,3.921
      c0,1.506,1.505,1.505,4.867,1.821c2.344,0.219,3.902-0.511,4.763,0.117c1.746-1.201,3.76-2.399,5.432-2.886
      C76.161,403.198,75.389,405.162,77.774,405.863z"/>

    <path fill="url(#img-3)" data-img="img-3" stroke="#646464" d="M167.006,368.053c-0.596-1.438-3.157-2.315-3.999-3.157s-0.281-4.771,0.421-6.945
      c0.702-2.174,1.263-3.156,0.982-4.98s-5.366-3.473-6.734-4.841s-3.297-3.297-5.331-6.454c-2.035-3.157-4.35-2.034-9.12-2.665
      c-4.77-0.632-4.349,0.28-6.173,0.28s0,2.806,0.351,3.929s-0.421,2.736-1.824,1.895s-2.736-2.176-4.279-4.631
      c-1.543-2.454-2.456-1.754-3.929-3.228c-1.473-1.473-6.594,0.913-7.646,1.403c-1.052,0.491-3.963,2.421-4.84,1.544
      c-0.877-0.878-1.543-3.228-3.367-4.35s-1.298,5.857-1.894,6.454c-0.597,0.596-3.087,7.085-2.525,8.278
      c0.562,1.192-0.141,2.244-0.141,3.156c0,0.913-2.736,2.034-3.718,2.315c-0.982,0.281-2.596,1.332-2.596,1.894
      c0,0.551-0.979,5.111-1.513,4.781c-0.112,1.348-0.518,2.489-1.504,2.865c-2.946,1.122-2.035,3.999-2.035,4.981
      c0,0.981-1.753,3.437-1.753,4.489c0,1.052-0.07,2.596,1.192,4.56s0.807,5.576,1.403,6.173c0.597,0.598,3.858,0.982,1.789,1.789
      s-5.998,0.808-6.489,2.14c-0.491,1.333-4.735,1.929-5.472,2.666c-0.737,0.736-3.647,2.875-4.63,4.84s-1.473,3.086-1.473,4.841
      c0,1.754,0,4.489-2.386,3.788c-2.385-0.701-1.613-2.665-5.472-1.543c-1.672,0.486-3.686,1.685-5.432,2.886
      c0.374,0.272,0.618,0.797,0.734,1.772c0.384,3.222-0.071,9.665-0.071,10.121c0,0.454,0,0.805-0.385,1.188
      c-0.385,0.386-0.805,0.981-0.805,1.892c0,0.912,2.837,0.771,4.097,0.35c1.261-0.419,4.832-1.819,6.934-1.364
      c2.101,0.454,7.896,3.624,8.544,4.272c0.647,0.648,3.816,1.154,4.062,3.815c0.245,2.66-2.171,3.012-2.346,3.816
      c-0.175,0.806-1.172,1.77-1.751,2.348c-0.578,0.577-1.401,0.874-1.995,1.05c-0.595,0.176-0.263,1.664-0.035,1.891
      c0.228,0.227,2.801-0.385,3.991-1.017c1.19-0.63,4.238-0.943,7.844-0.734c3.606,0.209,4.482,3.571,6.793,4.201
      c2.311,0.631,3.571-0.805,3.921-1.89c0.351-1.087,2.941,0.104,3.327-1.156c0.385-1.26,3.274-6.041,3.852-6.618
      s4.027-0.734,6.863-1.576c2.836-0.84,8.999-4.481,9.419-6.197c0.419-1.716,4.587-5.495,5.708-5.742
      c1.12-0.245,3.432-0.489,3.677-1.751c0.245-1.26-1.016-2.205-2.066-1.996c-1.05,0.211-1.156,0.422-2.662-0.279
      c-1.506-0.7,0.596-2.941,0.875-4.308c0.281-1.366-1.715-0.664-1.925-5.006c-0.211-4.342,1.855-7.039,4.762-6.863
      c2.907,0.174,4.833-0.806,5.113-2.558c0.28-1.75,0.42-5.601-0.036-6.547c-0.456-0.945-1.961,1.226-2.835,1.226
      c-0.876,0-1.786-4.762-0.841-6.688c0.946-1.928,0.806-1.646-0.14-4.098c-0.945-2.45,5.428-2.45,6.688-2.45
      c1.26,0,0.979,0.735,1.75,1.506c0.771,0.769,3.117,0.209,3.782,0.559c0.665,0.352,2.328,2.436,3.012,3.117
      c0.264,0.264,0.462,0.376,0.633,0.39c0.739-1.667,2.02-3.534,2.25-4.5c0.351-1.473,1.333-1.753,5.401-3.016
      S167.603,369.49,167.006,368.053z"/>


  </g>

</svg>
```

[Полный пример на codepen](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/GPpbPj?editors=0010)